# Using Kendo UI Grid, how do i create a custom toolbar that has a button that links back to an Action in my Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here is my code below.  I need to link the onclick to my Action in my controller for the toolbar button.

```
<script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                            dataSource: {
                                      transport: {
                                          read: { url: '@Url.Action("GetCars", "Home")' }
                                pageSize: 20,
                                serverPaging: true,
                                serverSorting: true,
                                serverFiltering: true
                            },
                            toolbar: [ { name: "create", text: "Add a new car" }],
                            height: 550,
                            sortable: true,
                            pageable: true,
                            columns: [
                                { field: "ProductID", title: "Product ID", width: 100 },
                                { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
                                { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", width: 150 },
                                { field: "QuantityPerUnit", title: "Quantity Per Unit" }
                            ]
                        });
    </script>
```

The way i always did it in Razor was:

```
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Text("Add new car").Action("Create", "Home"))
```

Comment: Have you tried `{ url: '/Home/GetCars' }`? Or rather, if you look at what `@Url.Action('GetCars', 'Home')` returns, then you can just paste that in instead.

Comment: Yeah i tried that.  Nothing.  Im confused as to what your saying about the Url.Action('getCars, 'Home') returns?

Comment: It's a function that returns a string.

Comment: My Create action is returning another view.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question from the start. Looking at it again, I realized you don't have a `create` transport defined in your grid's `dataSource`. You only have `read` defined. So, clicking your _Add a new car_ button won't post anything to the server. [Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.create)

Comment: I tried adding create: { url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Home")' } and that didnt work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem.

```
toolbar: [{ name:"create", template: "<input type='submit' value='Add
      new' onclick=\"location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Home")'\" />" }],
```